# Will omega 7 make it harder to produce high quality meat?

Tags: zoology

I heard from a medical show that Omega 7 makes it harder to gain weight, and was wondering if I would be be able to put on muscle better if I have sheep and pigs getting omega 7 through sea berry branches.

Comment: can you add some references/information sources? which medical show? is it published anywhere? etc etc

Comment: https://vimeo.com/107166478

Answer (score 1):

No. The only sure thing about omega-7 is that the suppliers are making money.

There's no evidence that it's doing anything more than just being an unsaturated fat in humans. This make it extremely unlikely that it would do anything after you put it through a pig.

Comment: So if your trees are producing it, you will be making more money?